How can I check the contents of the .demo file?
I generated demo files (my play data) using the ml-agent package in Unity. How can I check how that file is structured? When I open the file with a text viewer, it is full of unintelligible text. I know that the demo file contains states, actions, and return values, but I want to see how they are described.

I haven't used ml-agents yet, but it's open source (Apache 2 license). I think the best starting point would be this importer for demo files.
